# Problems with residue at infinity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I know I've asked a similar question before, but this function gives me headaches.
Let $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z^2*(z^2+9)}.$ Calculate residue in isolated singularity (inclusive infinity)
I calculated the residue in all singularities: $3i,$ $ -3i$ and $ 0, $ but at infinity I got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**:  Consider the circle of radius $4$ with positive orientation.  On one side, the three poles you mention in your question.  On the other side, all the other poles.  Since the denominator *only* gives the three poles you mention and the numerator only gives a pole at infinity, *and* the function is meromorphic, putting the negative orientation on the circle, it only encloses the pole at $\infty$.  Since reversing the path of an integral negates its value, the residue of pole at $\infty$ is minus the sum of the residues of the poles you found.

**Method 2**:  For a [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity), let $z \mapsto 1/w$ and expand $(-1/w^2)f(1/w)$ in a Laurent expansion in the variable $w$.  (Recall that a residue is an integral.  The change of variable changes the differential element: $\mathrm{d}z = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}w} w^{-1} \,\mathrm{d}w = -w^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}w$, which explains the source of the $(-1/w^2)$.)  Here, this gives \begin{align*}
\frac{-1}{w^2}f(1/w) &= \frac{-w^2 \mathrm{e}^{1/w}}{1+9w^2}  \\
&= -w^2 \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(1/w)^j}{j!}  \right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-9w^2)^k  \text{.}\end{align*}
To get the coefficient of the $w^{-1}$, we need the coefficient of $w^{-3}$ in $-\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}w^{-j}  \right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-9)^kw^{2k}$.  Contributions to that coefficient occur when $2k-j = -3$, so, $j = 2k+3$.  ... blah, shift the index, blah, recognize a sine series (maybe), blah ...  This seems hard because the powers are running in opposite directions (through negative integers in $j$ and through positive evens in $k$).

**Method 2 (fixed)**: As in the previous attempt, but make the powers run in the same direction.
\begin{align*}
\frac{-1}{w^2}f(1/w) &= \frac{-w^2 \mathrm{e}^{1/w}}{1+9w^2}  \cdot \frac{1/(9w^2)}{1/(9w^2)}  \\
&= \frac{-1}{9} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{1/w}}{(1/9)w^{-2} + 1}  \\
&= \frac{-1}{9} \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{w^{-j}}{j!}  \right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{9} w^{-2}\right)^k  \text{.}
\end{align*}
(Another way to say this:  If you are expanding in powers of $1/w = w^{-1}$ make sure you expand *everything* in powers of $w^{-1}$.  Your change of variable has moved the singularity to $0$ so to make sure you are working with series convergent on the annulus with inner radius $0$, choose the power series that blow up there.)  Now the $w^{-1}$ term receives contributions when $-j-2k=-1$, $j+2k=1$, so only from the $j = 1$ and $k = 0$ terms.
$$  \frac{-1}{9}\left(\frac{w^{-1}}{1!}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{9} w^{-2}\right)^0 = \frac{-1}{9}  $$
and we get the same residue as from Method 1.

Could we avoid using a big theorem (Method 1) or messing around with series (Methods 2)?  Not really; the singularity at $\infty$ of $\mathrm{e}^z$ is at infinity and is essential, so the usual tricks ($\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} (z-\infty)f(z)$ for a simple pole and $\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \rightarrow c} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{n-1}} ((z-\infty)^n f(z))$) are useless.  This means either we find a theorem to do the work for us, or we have to use Laurent expansion.